# Nginx - Upstream SSL - peer closed connection in SSL handshake

Tags: ssl, nginx

I am getting this error:

> Error frontend: 502 Bad gateway
>
> 99.110.244:443
>
> 2017/09/28 13:03:51 [error] 34080#34080: *1062 peer closed connection in SSL handshake (104: Connection reset by peer) while SSL handshaking to upstream, client: 10.210.0.81, server: webshop.domain.be, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "https://10.1.10.61:443/", host: "webshop.domain.be"

Config:

```
        # Zone voor connection logging
        limit_conn_zone $binary_remote_addr zone=izSSL_webshop-api_CZ:10m;

        # Zone voor rate logging
        # Hoge rate limit.  x r/s is soms wat snel
        # 10 MB (10m) will give us enough space to store a history of 160k requests.
        limit_req_zone $binary_remote_addr zone=izSSL_webshop-api_RZ:10m rate=20r/s;


upstream webshop_domain_be {
        server webshop.domain.be:443;
}


server {
        listen       443 ssl;
        server_name  webshop.domain.be webshop;

        client_max_body_size 80M;

        ssl_session_cache    shared:webshopSSL:1m;
        ssl_session_timeout  10m;
        ssl_certificate /var/www/certs/webshop.domain.be/webshop.domain.be-chain.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key /var/www/certs/webshop.domain.be/webshop.domain.be-key.pem;
        ssl_verify_client off;
        ssl_protocols        SSLv3 TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;

        ssl_ciphers RC4:HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;


        location / {

                proxy_ssl_session_reuse off;
                proxy_pass $scheme://webshop_domain_be;

        }
}
```

nginx version: **nginx/1.10.3 (Ubuntu)**

Other server (10.1.10.61) is an IIS Server with the **same certificate** as I'm using in this proxy (correct?). It's not an IIS problem; and the proxy server can reach 10.1.10.61 / port 443

Config based on https://serverfault.com/questions/583374/configure-nginx-as-reverse-proxy-with-upstream-ssl

I am using Let's Encrypt certificates.

Comment: Try adding `proxy_ssl_server_name on;` to your proxy_pass block and see if it helps

Comment: Tried it, but doesn't work either. Thanks though.

Comment: How come both names are `webshop.domain.be` ?

Comment: Oh, yes, it's something stupid, but the vendor specifically asked it to be that way rather than the IP. Anyhow, even with IP it makes no difference.

(the trick is: the proxy server is known as this name in all our DNS records, but in /etc/hosts of the proxy it is overruled and refers to the other one)

Comment: Try changing `webshop.domain.be:443` to the actual ip. And use `proxy_ssl_name "webshop.domain.be"`. If that doesn't work try adding `proxy_ssl_server_name on;` as well

Comment: You're my hero Tarun! Thank you very much!

Comment: Post what worked and whether `proxy_ssl_server_name` was needed or not, so i will document the answer

Comment: @TarunLalwani: Just had this same issue and the "proxy_ssl_server_name" option was the solution for me.  Thanks!

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: adding proxy_ssl_server_name on; to your proxy_pass block worked for me. Thanks

Comment: [Securing HTTP Traffic to Upstream Servers | NGINX Documentation](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/security-controls/securing-http-traffic-upstream/)

Answer (score 37):

Adding this line after the proxy_pass worked for me.

```
proxy_ssl_server_name on;
```

Before that I did this from [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/791205/centos7-dont-trust-certificate-issued-by-lets-encrypt)

In REDHAT 7/ CentOS 7/ Oracle Linux 7:
Install the certificate in your environment.

1. Download Active PEM certificate from: https://letsencrypt.org/certificates/ in `/etc/pki/ca-trust/source/anchors`
2. Execute: `sudo update-ca-trust`

Not sure if those last 2 steps needed, but doing both worked for me.

Answer (score 15):

I had had this issue and I had to this to my location block:

```
proxy_ssl_name your.proxiedserver.name;
proxy_ssl_server_name on;
```

Answer (score 7):

Here is what worked for me. I had a server section with server_name setup with a wildcard search and had to do the following in the location section:

```
proxy_ssl_name $host;
proxy_ssl_server_name on;
proxy_pass https://istio-ingress-gateway
```

Comment: this saved me when using an external Load balancer in another K8 cluster that forwards requests from my DMZ into a secondary cluster where my service lies that uses Istio.

Answer (score 2):

Change your upstream to use the IP

```
upstream webshop_domain_be {
        server <IP>:443;
}
```

And then change your `proxy_pass` block to

```
location / {
   proxy_ssl_session_reuse off;
   proxy_ssl_server_name "webshop.domain.be";
   proxy_pass $scheme://webshop_domain_be;
}
```

If the above doesn't work then add `proxy_ssl_server_name on;` also to the config

Comment: At the time of writing, you can't set the proxy_ssl_server_name to being anything other than on or off.

Comment: adding `proxy_ssl_session_reuse off;` helped me to get rid of the `peer closed connection in SSL handshake while SSL handshaking to upstream` and `SSL_do_handshake() failed (SSL: error:14094438:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:tlsv1 alert internal error:SSL alert number 80) while SSL handshaking to upstream` errors that appeared randomly when proxying my Tomcat instance. But I need more testing though. Also I need to mention, that downgrading nginx to version 1.22 helps even without a need of `proxy_ssl_session_reuse off;`

Answer (score 0):

To improve the other answer I would say that

`upstream` is really important

For simple redirect from one domain into another just use this:

```
http {
....
upstream someserver {
        server your.domain.name.com:443;
}

location / {
   proxy_pass https://someserver;
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

i use this @nginx

```
ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:10m;
ssl_session_timeout 1h;
ssl_buffer_size 4k;
```

with

```
grep worker_processes /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
worker_processes auto; <<<-- auto not the default value "1"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
server {
        listen 443 ssl;
        server_name webshop1.domain.be;

        location / {
            proxy_set_header Host webshop2.domain.ce;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
            proxy_pass https://webshop2.domain.ce/api/web/qrcode/;
        }
}
```