# Proxy HTTP requests to an HTTPS server in nginx

Tags: ssl, nginx, https, proxy, reverse-proxy

I would like to set up an nginx instance which would proxy HTTP requests starting in /api to an HTTPS server, but the /api URL segment should be omitted out.
For example, the instance should listen to localhost:9817. And if it receives a request to http://localhost:9817/api/auth, it should proxy it as https://api.com:8443/auth.

Here is my nginx config:

```
events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
    server {
        listen       9817;
        server_name  localhost;

        location /api {
            rewrite  ^/api(/.*) $1 break;
            proxy_pass https://api.com:8443;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
        }

        location / {
            root  "D:/Project/dist";
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
        }
    }
}
```

However, I get the following error in error.log:

```
2020/01/16 17:54:22 [error] 420512#426216: *31 peer closed connection in SSL handshake (10054: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host) while SSL handshaking to upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: localhost, request: "POST /api/auth HTTP/1.1", upstream: "https://16.53.35.38:8443/auth", host: "localhost:9817", referrer: "http://localhost:9817/"
```

What is the reason for this error? How can I fix it or set up proxying as I want to?

Comment: Hello, I get same error. Google don't known about this error. Do you fix this error?

Comment: Hello! No, I did not. Such proxying became no longer needed on my project, so the problem became irrelevant.

Comment: [Securing HTTP Traffic to Upstream Servers | NGINX Documentation](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/security-controls/securing-http-traffic-upstream/)

Answer (score 20):

I got same problem.
I found magic action to fix it in this [stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46467613/nginx-upstream-ssl-peer-closed-connection-in-ssl-handshake)

"Try adding proxy_ssl_server_name on; to your proxy_pass block and see if it helps"

It was in my nginx.conf

```
   location / {
    proxy_pass https://$http_x_forwarded_to; 
}
```

After editing it became

```
   location / {
    proxy_pass https://$http_x_forwarded_to; 
    proxy_ssl_server_name on;
}
```

I can enjoy life again

Comment: I have just tried to reproduce the situation that I described in the question. And it somehow works! There is just no error. Even without your solution. Probably, the problem was because of something other than the nginx config. Anyway, thanks for participation!

Comment: The error was only for requests to a specific address(https://bla-bla.api.kz). Everything worked for other addresses without the changes.
What was the anomaly of the problem server - I did not understand

Comment: your approach redirect only ? how to proxy with no change on host ?