# Nginx error: *1 peer closed connection in SSL handshake

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, nginx, ssl, https

I have an asp.net app in docker container. I used certbot to set https.

Error:

```
*8 peer closed connection in SSL handshake (104: Connection reset by peer) while SSL handshaking to upstream, client: 220.152.160.127, server: api.domain.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "https://127.0.0.1:7443/", host: "api.example.org"
```

Docker ports binding:

7080 -> 80

7443 -> 443

Nginx config:

```
upstream api{
    server 127.0.0.1:7443;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/api.example.org/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/api.example.org/privkey.pem;
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf;
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem;
    
    server_name api.example.org;
    location / {
        proxy_ssl_server_name on;
        proxy_pass $scheme://api;
    }
}

server{
    if ($host = api.example.org) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    listen 80;
    server_name api.example.org;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot


}
```

I have some other containers where this config works fine.

Full nginx config:

[Config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LT8pO.png)

[App Program.cs file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aixjM.png)

Redirect in app set to 7443

Comment: Here is your answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46467613/nginx-upstream-ssl-peer-closed-connection-in-ssl-handshake

TLDR: add `proxy_ssl_server_name on;` directive after your `proxy_pass $scheme://api;`

Comment: I saw that answer. It didn't help. So the problem is still there. Also tried this config
```proxy_ssl_name $host;
proxy_ssl_server_name on;
proxy_pass https://istio-ingress-gateway```

Comment: Could you provide us with full nginx configuration? 

Also, all of your `location` directives should go after `server {}` block directives such as `listen`, `ssl_*`, `include`, etc.

Comment: Changed my question. Added full config file. Also moved the location directive to the end. Still has the problem.

Comment: what is configuration of `127.0.0.1:7443`, what actually handles requests on `7443` port of your `localhost`?

Comment: It's a asp net app in docker container.  Docker ps: `ff0984aa1156   gbsyi/myapiapp:latest   "dotnet MyApiApp"   37 hours ago   Up 37 hours   0.0.0.0:7080->80/tcp, :::7080->80/tcp, 0.0.0.0:7443->443/tcp, :::7443->443/tcp         myapiapp
`

Comment: Okay, what config is actually running behind `127.0.0.1:7443` server?